# pandas datetime: groupy hourly and every monday

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, hour, weekday

I'm new to pandas / python: 
I have a `dataframe` (events.number) indexed by a `datetime` object.

I'm trying to extract an event count hourly, on every Monday (or other particular weekday). I wrote:

```
hour_tally_monday = events.number.groupby(lambda x: (x.hour & x.weekday==0) ).count()
```

but this does not work correctly.

I can drop the "`& x.weekday==1`" and it works but presumably uses all the days in the frame. What's the right (simplest) syntax to just average over Mondays?

Comment: try using comma "," instead of "&"

Comment: documentation is always useful: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you need first filter dataframe with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.to_datetime('2016-02-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2016-02-25')
rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='12H')

events = pd.DataFrame({'number': [1] * 20 + [2] * 15 + [3] * 14}, index=rng)
print events
                     number
2016-02-01 00:00:00       1
2016-02-01 12:00:00       1
2016-02-02 00:00:00       1
2016-02-02 12:00:00       1
2016-02-03 00:00:00       1
2016-02-03 12:00:00       1
2016-02-04 00:00:00       1
2016-02-04 12:00:00       1
2016-02-05 00:00:00       1
2016-02-05 12:00:00       1
2016-02-06 00:00:00       1
2016-02-06 12:00:00       1
2016-02-07 00:00:00       1
...
...
```

```
filtered = events[events.index.weekday == 0]
print filtered
                     number
2016-02-01 00:00:00       1
2016-02-01 12:00:00       1
2016-02-08 00:00:00       1
2016-02-08 12:00:00       1
2016-02-15 00:00:00       2
2016-02-15 12:00:00       2
2016-02-22 00:00:00       3
2016-02-22 12:00:00       3
```

In version `0.18.1` you can use new method [`DatetimeIndex.weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday_name.html):

```
filtered = events[events.index.weekday_name == 'Monday']
print filtered
                     number
2016-02-01 00:00:00       1
2016-02-01 12:00:00       1
2016-02-08 00:00:00       1
2016-02-08 12:00:00       1
2016-02-15 00:00:00       2
2016-02-15 12:00:00       2
2016-02-22 00:00:00       3
2016-02-22 12:00:00       3

print filtered.groupby(filtered.index.hour).size()
0     4
12    4
dtype: int64
```